# MercadoPago con laravel 5.4 error notificaciones

Tags: laravel-5, mercadopago

Estoy usando para integrar mercadopago a laravel un paquete de https://github.com/santigraviano/laravel-mercadopago y configure el botón y al configurar la url de notificaciones en Mercadopago me tira el siguiente error:

> La URL ingresada no responde un HTTP status correcto. Debe responder
>   200 o 201.

La url es: https://mptest.app/notifications

En el archivo de rutas tengo:

```
Route::get('notifications', 'HomeController@notificationsMP');
```

Y el método es:

```
public function notificationsMP(Request $r) {

   return header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    return \Response::json(['HTTP/1.1 200 OK'], 200);
}
```

Si hay otro paquete que recomienden o como implementar mercadopago directamente desde su documentación (sin paquetes) bienvenido sea.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el estado que responde la URL?

Comment: Me responde 200, el tema que nose si tendrá que ver que yo estoy queriendo probar esto en localhost

Comment: Probablemente, asumo que estás haciendo una solicitud a MercadoPago y su servicio intenta llamar dicha URL, la cual probablemente no exista "en la nube".

Comment: Por eso necesito probar en modo sandbox pero no logro hacer andar!

Comment: Puedes usar algo como ngrok para probar.

Comment: Barbaro, lo voy a ver !!

Comment: Tengo entendido que no se puede probar la IPN de mercadopago con localhost.

Comment: Este curso te será de utilidad: https://www.acamica.com/cursos/105/la-api-mercadolibre-conceptos-finales Saludos :D

Comment: y este otro también! https://www.acamica.com/cursos/62/introduccion-a-la-api-de-mercadolibre

Answer (score 3):

1- Las notificaciones no funcionan en localhost
2- La ruta tiene que ser POST

> Siempre que suceda un evento relacionado a alguno de los recursos
>   mencionados, te enviaremos una notificación en formato json usando
>   HTTP POST a la URL que especificaste.
>   https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/webhooks/

3- Tenes que agregar la ruta en protected $except en el Middleware VerifyCsrfToken.php

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde yo entiendo esto debería ser un post:

```
Route::get('notifications', 'HomeController@notificationsMP');
```

Luego como es un post, vas a tener que ir a : `VerifyCsrfToken.php`

y agregar lo siguiente:

```
protected $except = [
        'notifications',
    ];
```

Como te deja hacer la verificación correctamente, pero luego se supone que tu función debería de ejecutar algo y ahí es donde me pierdo.

Solo me funciona si tiene

```
 return header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
 return \Response::json(['HTTP/1.1 200 OK'], 200);
```